# how to open a form only when app runs the first time

Tags: c#

I have tried this but it didn't work. I would appreciate if you could help me out ............................................

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        string filename = "counter.txt";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, "1");
            Application.Run(new FormLogin());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is the full path of the file name you appear to be using to determine if this is the initial execution?  Also, there are User and Machine level settings that can be created with default values and updated and stored for future use.

Comment: There are plenty of question discussing reading and writing files (in particular talking about relative vs. absolute path as @codemaker hinted)... Also plain text file is last place to store settings - there are much better alternatives with plenty of samples - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+save+application+configuration+runtime... Overall current state of the post is unclear an shows no research you've presumably performed to solve the problem (and hence likely to be closed as unclear and potentially downvoted. Consider [edit] to clarify/improve).